# Java HotSpot analysis before deployment?

Tags: java, jit, jvm-hotspot

It is well known that HotSpot analyses runtime usage patterns and performance characteristics and then optimises the JIT process based on that analysis as a Java application is running.  As a result, caution is often recommended when attempting to benchmark Java applications so that this analysis and optimation phase is allowed to occur before the actual performance measurements are taken.

I am sure this has been thought of before but I have often wondered why this analysis phase (e.g. typical usage patterns) cannot be done somehow as part of the build process and then the profiling data deployed along with the application so that full-speed JIT is achieved immediately when the application is launched.

Does anyone know whether this is actually done, if there is a reason why this is not feasible or if this is being planned as an enhancement to HotSpot and Java application deployment?

Comment: Well, speaking out of intuition, for it to analyse, it would have to more-or-less run the code, or step through it with some kind of logic. It also can't really predict user input, which will eventually have a pattern. It gets a nice sample set of data as you run the program

Comment: Yes, but there are always going to be some very typical usage patterns that could easily be profiled before deployment.  Why can't profiling info for those patterns be deployed?  There will always be less common usage patterns but they could be analysed and optimised in the same way that HotSpot works now at actual run time.

Comment: What "very typical usage patterns"?  If you pick out a random `int` variable in the middle of a program, can you determine whether it's likely to be below 50 just by looking at the code?

Comment: And I am sure for some simpler applications that the execution paths are very limited so that almost all typical usage patterns can be predicted and analysed prior to any end user ever getting hold of the application.  It just seems a little redundant for HotSpot to re-analyse these patterns *every* time the application is launched.

Comment: @FelixBembrick The whole logic of: In this case it may be easy, and in this case it may be easy, is exactly what makes it difficult. As a human you can often spot these things easily. Computers however often have to work in general. You can't just code giant if statements checking different cases, and analysing if this is in fact one of those cases. However it does do as much as it can at compile time, to at least make the byte code as efficient as it can attempt.

Answer (score 0):

There is no “typical usage pattern” for an application, especially when talking about a Java application. It can run under Windows, Linux, MacOS, Solaris, etc. The runtime environment does not only change the behavior of the code completely, it decides which classes will even exist at runtime.

For example, an application with a graphical user interface will load different AWT implementation classes under Windows, Linux or MacOS. But even the simple property of the display’s pixel format (RGB vs. BGR, 16 Bit vs 24 Bit) will led the application take different code paths. And there are new JRE versions released continuously improving the code of the JFC classes thus changing the runtime behavior making any pre-computed profiling data useless.

It is a typical mistake to think testing and benchmarking on a developer’s computer are sufficient to say anything about the real production environment. What may looked like sufficient might turn out as completely unusable when running with billions of concurrent transactions, or, on the other side, on a customer’s PC with only half the RAM.

It is one of the strength of Java to be able to profile and optimize against the real behavior and usage pattern of the software and to optimize across the boundaries of the libraries from different vendors using the exact versions found at runtime.